# How to add remote script to chrome extension Content Security Policy?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a simple chrome extension to show case satismeter for demo calls.
All the code I have so far is available there: https://github.com/fmaume/Chrome_extension_satismeter_demo

In order to work, I would need to enable resources from https://app.satismeter.com/satismeter.js

I try to follow this instructions from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

I added this line to the manifesto

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://app.satismeter.com/satismeter.js; object-src 'self'"
```

When I try to install the Chrome extension: I'm getting the error: "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive '"script-src'."
Any idea why?

Comment: I don't see this error when I install it from your github repo so you must be seeing the old error (they're not auto-cleared). Note however that relaxing the CSP is less reliable than including the script within the extension itself.